# Filling a char* in C

Tags: c, arrays

This is probably a very simple solution, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I'm trying to create a `char` array (so a `char*`) consisting of numbers from 0 to `numPlayers - 1`, which I will iterate through to access whose turn it is. So, if `numPlayers = 10`, I want `gameState.players` to be `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. What did I do wrong?

```
printf("How many players will be playing: ");
  scanf(" %d", &numPlayers);

  gameState.players = (char*) malloc(numPlayers * sizeof(char));

  for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
    strcpy(gameState.players[i],(char) i);
  }
```

Comment: `strcpy(gameState.players[i],(char) i);`  -> `gameState.players[i] = i;`

Comment: On average, there's something wrong with every single line of that code.

Comment: A char array is not a char*

Comment: You should explain why you are using a `char` array. Is it because you want to store a character for each number, or because you only want to use a byte for each number? Study the difference between a character (`char`), a string (`char*`), a byte (8 bits, also a `char`) and an integer (eg. `int`).

Comment: When you say "[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" are those supposed to be digits or numbers? Are you using "0" to represent the number zero or the digit zero? Ditto for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off:

```
gameState.players = (char*) malloc(numPlayers * sizeof(char));
```

The explicit cast is ill-advised in C (it can hide certain subtle errors) and the multiplication by `sizeof(char)` is *never* needed - it's *always* one.

But the *real* problem lies here:

```
strcpy(gameState.players[i],(char) i);
```

The `str*` functions are meant to work with C *strings* (null terminated character arrays). You do not *have* a string, rather you have a character value, so it should be more along the lines of:

```
gameState.players[i] = i;
```

You also need to keep in mind:

- Though you're using `char` variables, the value being put in is not the textual representation of the digit. To get that, you would need to use `i + '0'`<sup>(a)</sup>. Characters are generally meant to be used for (mostly) printable stuff, you would be better off using a more-specific data type like `int` or unsigned short` for non-character data.
- This scheme (assuming you *want* textual representation) is going to break horribly if you ever use more than ten items.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> There's a big difference between the "characters" `7` and `'7'`. The former actually has the value `7` (ASCII BEL, if you're using ASCII), the latter has the value `0x37` (again, assuming ASCII/Unicode).

The numeric characters are the only ones guaranteed to be consecutive so you can convert a numeric value `0..9` to the printable character value simply by adding `'0'`.

Comment: "`sizeof(char)` is never needed", true, though it does provide self-documenting code.

Comment: "To get that, you would need to use i + '0'." Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: @Ismael As you may know `char` is treated as a numeric type in C. `char ch = 8;` for example will give you character number 8, which happens to be backspace. If you wanted the character that looks like two circles on top of each other - you know, this one -->8<-- - then you need to use 56 (which its ASCII number) or '8' (which is an easier way so you don't have to look up the number).

Comment: @Heath, I think one would be better off just learning the fact the `malloc` works in characters - then the `malloc` *without* a multiplier is all the documentation you need, rather than clogging up code with unnecessary gumpf :-)

Comment: @Ismael take a look at [ASCIItable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/). Look at the ASCII value for the *character* `'0'`. It is `48` (or `0x30` hex). Of course the *decimal* value of `0` is just zero. So to get the character value of `'0'`, you add `'0'` to the digit to get the ASCII *character* value (which is only valid for single digits `0-9`)

Comment: Also all the ASCII numbers for digits are consecutive, that means if you have a number `n` that's 0 through 9, then 48+n will give you the ASCII code for that digit.

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful when calling functions, you have to make sure that you are
using the correct types. If you use an incorrect one, the compiler will warn you
or print an error, you should read the warnings and errors of the compiler. They
tell you what is wrong.

`strcpy` is used to copy strings. The signature of the functions is

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

it expects a pointer to `char` as destination, and a pointer to `char` as the
source. Also `strcpy` expects a valid C-String. A C-Strings is a sequence of
`char` bytes that ends with the value `'\0'`. If you don't have a valid
C-String, you cannot use `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(gameState.players[i],(char) i)
```

Is wrong on many levels:

1. The arguments are **not** pointers of `char`
2. You are not dealing with valid C-strings
3. Casting won't help you here, you even did the wrong casting.
4. 1 is not the same as `'1'`. The character `'1'` is actually the vakue 49
   (ASCII code). If you want to get the ASCII representation of a digit, you have
   to do: `'0' + digit`.

You should do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
    gameState.players[i] = '0' + i;
}
```

Note that this would only work for max. 9 players. If you need more, then you
have to use an array of strings.

Also note that `gameState.players` does not point to a C-String, because it is
**not** `'\0'`-terminated. You cannot calls strings functions on it. If you want
to do that, then you have to change your code like this:

```
printf("How many players will be playing: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf(" %d", &numPlayers);

if(numPlayers > 9)
{
    // error, do not continue
}

gameState.players = calloc(numPlayers + 1, sizeof *gameState.players);

for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
    gameState.players[i] = '0' + i;
}
```